# Makehuman render is blurry

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, makehuman

When importing a model from Madehuman, the render is always blurry. 
I try to understand why as the viewport is clear (see file).

I played with the camera settings, increase the light, I tried importing OJB, DEA files, changes materials, added subsurf, smooth shading, yet the render is  always blurry. 
I don't understand why. 
When I put other objects in the scene the render is just fine.

Any advise as to what I'm missing/doing wrong?

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mVxhjkzsKqDB46C3CyGgPeUA-PIvQsZ0)

Answer (score 0):

**it was just the intensity of sun light was too much, and you can increase the focal length of the camera to get more sharpness.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlgKk.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solved the problem... yet, it kept me a bit confused as for the why. Say if I would have created a sphere object with the default setting or even lower focal length, the object would still be sharp... which is not the case with the MakeHuman object/file. Also and at least until your answer, I used to believe that the viewport render image matched with a good correlation the rendered outcome. I.e. I know I'm missing something. Can you please help me to better understand?